# Will requiring express more than once incur an overhead?

Tags: javascript, express

What I mean by this is, I refactored my code so that I require it twice.  In one file I use it for the middleware it has.  In the other file I use it to actually create an app by calling it.

```
// index.js file ( entry point )

const express = require('express');
const app = require('./app');
// various middleware ...

// app.js file
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));
module.exports = app;
```

I'm assuming this is O.K because require is only locating a reference to express and I only create one app.

Comment: yes, this is fine

Comment: It's fine. Multiple `require` to a module will reference the same instance when it was first called. They are singletons in a sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly alright to require express in multiple files, since in nodejs, when requiring a module one of the steps involved is caching of the required file. So when a module is required again it doesn't have any overload.

Refer [this link](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8) for more on require

Comment: I marked the answer but I would like a reference for require.  The official documentation should be JavaScript ES6 I believe.

Comment: The official documentation is from https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require nodejs. Es6 instead has import.